# Is it possible to design website using tablets? And Which tablets support XAMPP?

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

I am trying to ditch my laptop for a tablet, and be able to practice PHP, HTML, CSS on the fly. But, I don't know which tablet to buy that can support even basic apps like 
Notepad++ and XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can build a website via notepad apps in tablets and NO there is not a XAMPP app for tablets except windows 8 tablets. BUT there are other types of server apps like XAMPP for android tablets.